# User control and data bind in c# win apps

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Suppose I have a user control in win application and that has few control like:

- Employee name - textbox
- Employee age  - textbox
- Employee sex  - combo
- etc...

Now I want to develop a generic user control in such a way that when I will assign something like `usercontrolInstance.Databind=mydataset`, then all the control will be populated with data.

If I can develop in this way then code will be reuse and approach will be professional.
I have no idea how could i develop user control in such a way where property called datasource will be there and when i assign my dataset to that property then all the textboxes in user control will be populated with data......

Please guide me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at these links:

- **[CodeProject: Implementing complex data binding in custom controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataBindCustomControls.aspx)**
- **[MSDN Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Simple Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-simple-data-binding?view=vs-2017)**
- **[Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Complex Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-complex-data-binding?view=vs-2017)**
- **[Walkthrough: Creating a User Control that Supports Lookup Databinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-lookup-data-binding?view=vs-2017)**